# REMOVEFILTERS and use new FILTER in a DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there any way to use REMOVEFILTER and then use new FILTER in a single DAX measure?

I want to remove filter from existing table and apply new ones to pick previous year. All of these works on slicers.

```
 Test A =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'Table A' ),
    REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Table C'[Year], 'Table C'[Month] ),
    FILTER (
        'Table A',
        'Table A'[Snapshot Date].[Year]
            = MAX ( 'Table B'[Snapshot Date].[Year] ) - 1
    )
)
```

Either REMOVEFILTERS is working or FILTER(All(Table A) is working but not both together.

Can I get some help here?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example ?